# How do you add the "local open" button to the quick access toolbar in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do you add the "local open" button to the quick access toolbar in Excel 2010? I can see the local open option in the file tab, but I can't find a way to add it to the Ribbon or quick access toolbar. Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Ribbon and click **Customize the Ribbon**. This will bring up the options panel, where you can also customize the Quick Access toolbar. You add commmands from the left pane to the right pane.  At the top, you can filter the commands on the left. Filter by the File Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check these link

[Customize the Quick Access Toolbar in Excel](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformatting/qt/090906-excel-autoformat-button.htm)

[Quick Access Toolbar](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/pq/g/81018quickbar.htm)

[Customize the Quick Access Toolbar- Office Support](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-HA010362102.aspx?CTT=1) - it have most of the details to  `Add a command to the Quick Access Toolbar` etc in the `What do you want to do?` list.

hope this help to customize in your way..

watch this [video](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/videos/video-add-commands-to-the-quick-access-toolbar-VA101838657.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010362102) to know this how it works