# Add "Open File Location" to Quick Access Toolbar in Excel 365

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, shortcuts

In my workflow I frequently need to open the explorer file location of a spreadsheet I'm working in, and it's tedious to click File -> Info -> Open File Location every time.

Is there a way to add that command to the Quick Access Toolbar? It doesn't show up in the command list,
[as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4agzD.png).

The following question/answer isn't relevant here, because it's about a different command.
[How do you add the "local open" button to the quick access toolbar in Excel 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/358791/how-do-you-add-the-local-open-button-to-the-quick-access-toolbar-in-excel-2010)

Answer (score 1):

Appears this snippet of VBA code will do the trick. You'll just need to figure out how to save to use for all workbooks, and, then add it to your QAT.

```
    Sub OpenFolder()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show ActiveWorkbook.Path
    End Sub
```

Comment: Using this snippet but following Andrew Tran's steps below, I was able to get a button working properly! Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>

This opens the containing folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open development tab -> open Visual Basic
2. Menu: insert -> module
3. Paste the following code under vbaproject(personal.xlsb)

```
Public Sub Opener()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogOpen).Show ActiveWorkbook.Path+"\\"
End Sub
```

4. Save and close the VBA
5. Modify quick access toolbar and add the macro Opener (remember to add icon as well)